# How to write a backslash \ And " in Text file with PHP

Tags: php, string, post

Post content is cmd commande line :  move "D:\my 1.txt" "D:\my 2.txt"

My php code :

```
if (!empty($_POST["mechat"])){
  $mechat = fopen("mechat","w"); 
  fwrite($mechat,$_POST['mechat']);
}
```

The wrong result : move \"D:\my 1.txt\" \"D:\my 2.txt\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove escape slashes from strings using the [`stripslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function.

So in your case, you'd want to use `fwrite($mechat,stripslashes($_POST['mechat']));` instead. That way, when you have characters that need to be escaped, the stripslashes function will do that for you, and it should output fine.

Comment: thank You !! fwrite($mechat,stripslashes($_POST['mechat'])); Work Fine !

Answer (score 3):

Probably [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) is enabled on your server. It automatically adds `\` before quotes characters in input variables in order to prevent SQL injections.

It is [no longer recommended](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php) to use it and it has been deprecated with the release of PHP 5.3 and removed as of PHP 5.4. You can [disable it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) or use the [stripslashes](http://php.net/stripslashes) function to remove the escaping characters from your input.

Answer (score 2):

PHP syntax reserves the '\' character. You can overwrite it by adding another backslash before any backslashes you have in your command. For example, make your command `move "D:\\my 1.txt" "D:\\my 2.txt"`. You can also use the `stripslashes` function built into PHP. This specifies them as valid characters, and PHP ignores them.